# Issue with converting object to float in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion, valueerror

I am working on a Python project and encountered an issue with converting an object to a float. I have a variable that contains a numeric value stored as an object. However, when I try to convert it to a float using the float() function, I get an error. Here's a sample of my code:

```
value = "3.14"
float_value = float(value)
```

The error message I receive is:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.14'
```

I have verified that the value is a string representation of a valid float. What could be causing this error, and how can I successfully convert the object to a float?

Comment: Is the string `3.14` or `'3.14'`?

Comment: The code shown is fine; it's not clear what is triggering your error.

Comment: I suggest you print ord(value[1]) should be 46. Might be 8228 - a.k.a. One Dot Leader rather than Full Stop

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate this problem as follows:

```
value = '3․14'
float(value)
```

This will generate:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3․14'
```

You will need to copy'n'paste the code shown here - i.e., don't re-type it.

The issue here is that what looks like a Full Stop isn't what you think it is. It's actually '\u2024' which is a Unicode One Dot Leader

Comment: It's a good guess, but this is not the same error message posted in the question. The error message has '3.14', which means the problem is not reproducible (and question should be edited before answers posted).

Comment: @wim This is **exactly** the same error message as shown in the question

Comment: It isn't, this 3․14 but the error in the question has 3.14, even in [the initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/602e08d7-c665-4d38-bb31-9d44f5a7c3c3/view-source). They actually render slightly differently in my browser..